# Dynamic opening of elements

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js13

I have an object with 100 elements and a block with a height of 300px, I use the react-table library, it displays them at once and it turns out that some elements go to the bottom of this block (like 10 is displayed, and 11 is halfway) I made a function that hides the elements that are displayed on half, but when rebooting the element displayed half is shown for 1 second, how can I prevent this from happening and the objects are immediately displayed in the required order? here is the code

`const TableBlock = ({ info = [], columns = [] }: Props) => {
const heightRef = useRef(null);

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleDisplay = () => {
        handleRowDisplay(heightRef, blockTopHeight);
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleDisplay);
    handleDisplay();

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleDisplay);
    };
}, []);

if (info.length === 0) {
    return <p className={style.textNotNews}>Сегодня данных нет</p>;
}

return (
    <Table
        components={{
            table: (props: Props<T>) => <table ref={heightRef} {...props} className={style.tableBlock} />,
            body: {
                cell: (props: Props<T>) => <td {...props} className={style.tableCell} />
            }
        }}
        columns={columns}
        data={info}
        rowKey={(record) => record.id}
        className={style.tableBlock}
    />
);
```

};`